# prove or disprove the statements about the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ prove or give a counterexample to the statements:

1) if $m(A)>0$ then $A$ must contain an open interval

2) if $A$ is s.t $m(A^{c})=0$ then $A$ is dense

Here is the solution proposed by the instructor:

1) False:  take $A=\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$

Since $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup (\mathbb{R\setminus Q})$
then $m(\mathbb{R})=m(\mathbb{Q}\cup (\mathbb{R\setminus Q}))\le m(\mathbb{Q})+m(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})$
As $m(\mathbb{R})=\infty$ then $m(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})=\infty>0$

Why $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ cannot contain an open interval?

2) True: If $A$ is not dense then $A^{c}$ contains an open interval and has therefore $m(A^{c})>0$

Can someone explain to me step by step this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1): Let $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb R$ be any non-empty open interval (that is $a < b$). Then as $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ there is an $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $a < q < b$. So $(a,b) \not\subseteq \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$.

For 2): Suppose $A$ were not dense. By definition that means, that $A$ does not intersect every open interval, so there is some $(a,b)$ with $a< b$ and $(a,b) \cap A = \emptyset$. So we must have $(a,b) \subseteq A^c$, so 
$$ 0 = m(A^c) \ge m\bigl((a,b)\bigr) = b-a > 0, $$
which is nonsense. So $A$ is dense.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Nice explanation. Is it a typo above in the sentence ''By definition that means, that $A^{c}$..'' shouldn't it be $A$ instead? and later $A$ and $A^{c}$ are disjoint?

Comment: Corrected. ${}{}$